# How to specify "NOT IN" for a joined collection in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have the following Objects: User and Role

I have a linking table in my database called user_role, which creates a many to many relationship which grants any user any role. On my java object, this relationship is mapped in such a way that the User has a collection called roles which is a list of type Role.

I have a service which searches for user by role. This is easy.

"select * from User u join u.roles as role where role.id in (:theRoleIWant)"

that works fine. Now however I want to return a list of users who do not have a role.

eg a base level user has a role 6 and an administrative user has a role 3. Users can have both of these roles, but for my query I am only interested in the base level users who DO NOT have role id 3. So i do this:

"select * from User u join u.roles as role where role.id in (6) and role.id not in (3)"

this continues to return users who have both roles. Is there something i'm missing here?

Thanks for your time,
Margaret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the one you exclude from that "NOT IN" is not the "User" but the "Role". so the user still shown in that query.

Just imagine you have user A with role 1 and 2 when you join this, this will became two row. So if you use "ROLE.ID NOT IN 1" you still have a row with user A that have role 2.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Angga I was able to take a different approach to the query altogether. This is what I ended up with:

```
select * from User u join u.roles as role where role.id in (:theRoleIWant) 
and not exists (select 1 from User inner_u join inner_u.roles as inner_role where inner_role.id in (:theRolesIWantToAvoid) and inner_u.id = u.id)
```

Annga I am marking your answer as correct as it helped my to find the actual syntax I required.